How do I run dpdk-dumpcap tool without the primary process crashing?
I'm trying to run dpdk-dumpcap 22.11.1 tool to capture packets received on one interface, but my primary process keeps crashing with one of the following signatures -
#0  0x00000000046585b1 in bucket_enqueue ()
#1  0x0000000004ce8b38 in rte_pcapng_copy ()
#2  0x0000000004c5319a in pdump_copy ()
#3  0x0000000004c53d7f in pdump_tx ()
#4  0x0000000004d78b02 in rte_eth_call_tx_callbacks ()
#5  0x000000000454f602 in rte_eth_tx_burst


#0  0x00000000046585b1 in bucket_dequeue ()
#1  0x0000000004ce8b38 in rte_pcapng_copy ()
#2  0x0000000004c5319a in pdump_copy ()
#3  0x0000000004c53d7f in pdump_tx ()
#4  0x0000000004d78b02 in rte_eth_call_tx_callbacks ()
#5  0x000000000454f602 in rte_eth_tx_burst

Keeping in mind my primary process is running with a time accuracy of nanoseconds, and also that the load on interface is high (~2gbps), I'm open to suggestions as to what I should try to resolve this such that I can capture packets without having crashed the primary process.
I have previously captured packets using dumpcap tool with the same primary process and it has worked fine. But with high load, it started crashing the primary with the provided signatures.
I'm assuming it is the time sensitive nature and the high load which is leading to the crash. I'm not very familiar with the dpdk-dumpcap code and have been trying to understand the same to move this ahead.
